# If Y closed subspace of reflexive Banach Space X, then Y and X/Y are reflexive

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to do this functional analysis problem and I'm having a hard time. The problem states:

Let $Y$ be a closed subspace of a reflexive Banach space $X$. Show that both $Y$ and $X/Y$ are reflexive.

It gives a hint to use a theorem which states:

Consider a closed subspace $Y$ of a normed space $X$. Let $I:Y\to X$ denote the inclusion map and $Q:X\to X/Y$ denote the quotient map. Then we may identify $Q^*$ with the inclusion map of $Y^\perp$ into $X^*$ and $I^*$ with the quotient map of $X^*$ onto $X^*/Y^\perp$

I was able to show that $Y$ is reflexive but not using the hint. I have found this problem other places but I do not understand the solutions. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.